# How to write to an element

Tags: javascript

I've got a styled template that I want to manipulate with JavaScript. Below I have a functioning version of my script. Problem is, it writes to the whole document...

```js
element = document.getElementById("backDrop");
document.addEventListener('click', promptFunction);

function promptFunction() {
  document.write(square(window.prompt('inputvar')));
}

function square(x) {
  return x * x;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #3A3C3D;
  /*alt color #CCA #3A3C3D*/
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*top stop the extended shadow element height from causing the page to scroll*/
}
.backDrop {
  background-color: #FFF;
  /*alt colors #ACA null #CCA*/
  height: 100vh;
  width: 720px;
  margin: auto;
}
.backDrop:before {
  /*for to get rid of backDrop shadow round-corners*/
  box-shadow: 0 -20px 20px 0 black;
  content: '';
  height: 200vh;
  position: absolute;
  /*not sure why this is necissary, but it I know it is.*/
  width: 720px;
}
```

```html
<div class="backDrop"></div>
```

What I'd rather do is set up the event listener to only listen to within a specified element, and to only write content to specified elements. Below you'll see an identical code to the one above, but with that modification. It doesn't work. Why not?

```js
var element = document.getElementById("backDrop");
element.addEventListener('click', promptFunction);

function pomptFunction() {
  element.innerHTML(square(window.prompt('inputvar')));
}

function square(x) {
  return x * x;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #3A3C3D;
  /*alt color #CCA #3A3C3D*/
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*top stop the extended shadow element height from causing the page to scroll*/
}
.backDrop {
  background-color: #FFF;
  /*alt colors #ACA null #CCA*/
  height: 100vh;
  width: 720px;
  margin: auto;
}
.backDrop:before {
  /*for to get rid of backDrop shadow round-corners*/
  box-shadow: 0 -20px 20px 0 black;
  content: '';
  height: 200vh;
  position: absolute;
  /*not sure why this is necissary, but it I know it is.*/
  width: 720px;
}
```

```html
<div class="backDrop"></div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("backDrop");` will look for `id` attribute which you do not have in your markup. Try this: `<div class="backDrop" id="backDrop"></div>`

Comment: function name is wrong `function pomptFunction() {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few issues, you have not assigned `id` to element hence `document.getElementById("backDrop")` will return `null`. Assign `id` to your element.

Also note `innerHTML` is not a method to be called, it's `DOM Property`

And a *typo* here: `promptFunction`

Try this:

```js
var element = document.getElementById("backDrop");
element.addEventListener('click', promptFunction);

function promptFunction() {
  element.innerHTML = square(window.prompt('inputvar'));
}

function square(x) {
  return x * x;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #3A3C3D;
  /*alt color #CCA #3A3C3D*/
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*top stop the extended shadow element height from causing the page to scroll*/
}
.backDrop {
  background-color: #FFF;
  /*alt colors #ACA null #CCA*/
  height: 100vh;
  width: 720px;
  margin: auto;
}
.backDrop:before {
  /*for to get rid of backDrop shadow round-corners*/
  box-shadow: 0 -20px 20px 0 black;
  content: '';
  height: 200vh;
  position: absolute;
  /*not sure why this is necissary, but it I know it is.*/
  width: 720px;
}
```

```html
<div class="backDrop" id="backDrop"></div>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/nme29bbv/1/)

Comment: I noticed your typo and corrected it before using the script --no big on that. The strangest thing though, it seems to function perfectly well in the snippet, but even if I replace all of my code with yours via copy paste, I can't seem to get it to function locally. I'll mark your answer as correct because I assume the remaining problems are relevant only to me. I wonder if I could send you some screen shots of my code in a discussion though and perhaps you could explain what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Place the script right before closing `</body>` tag

Comment: But I'm trying to run it from a linked JavaScript file in the head area

Comment: Bingo! Thank you very much.